# Sprites get terribly scaled

Tags: xna, c#, spritesheet, scale

I've been making a Space Invaders game in XNA for a while. I got the invaders animated and contained within an array. But when I call `spriteBatch.Draw` and debug the invaders sprites get a **huge** scale-up! Here is my code:

```
        public static Texture2D g_BotInvaderTex;
        public static Rectangle g_BotInvaderHitBox;
        public static Vector2 g_BotInvaderPos = new Vector2(0, 24);
        public static Vector2 g_BotInvaderOrigin;
        public static Rectangle[,] g_BotInvadersRect;
        int m_InvaderRows = 5;
        int m_InvaderCollumns = 10;
        public static Color InvadersColor = Color.White;

        // blah blah sprite animation logic

        public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Rectangle[,] destinationRect, Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRect, Color color, float rotation, Vector2 origin, SpriteEffects effects, float scale, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(g_BotInvaderTex, g_BotInvadersRect[r, c], g_BotInvaderHitBox, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
```

After I intialize the invader class in my Game1 and call Draw:

```
botInvader.Draw(botInvaders.g_BotInvaderTex, botInvaders.g_BotInvaderPos, botInvaders.g_BotInvadersRect, botInvaders.g_BotInvaderHitBox, Color.White, 0f, botInvaders.g_BotInvaderOrigin, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f, spriteBatch);
```

I don't think the sprites should be scaled up, after all I've given `1.0f` to the scale argument???

```
        for (int r = 0; r < m_InvaderRows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < m_InvaderCollumns; c++)
            {
                g_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Width = g_BotInvaderTex.Width;
                g_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Height = g_BotInvaderTex.Height;
                g_BotInvadersRect[r, c].X = 70 * c;
                g_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Y = 70 * r;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please tell us what debugging steps you've taken already.

Comment: If this is the code you are using it shouldn't compile. You are passing 10 arguments to a draw method with 5 parameters.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Edited @Dragonsdoom

Comment: @PowerUser the code examples are still incorrect. Your draw method can't accept the arguments you are sending to it.

Comment: @Dragonsdoom – Alright I just wrote the code without copy-pasting it, I did a mistake. Sorry, now everything must be fixed and all right.

Comment: From the msdn website:public void Draw(Texture2D texture,         Rectangle destinationRectangle, Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,         Color color)
 destinationRectangleType: Rectangle
A rectangle that specifies (in screen coordinates) the destination for drawing the sprite. If this rectangle is not the same size as the source rectangle, the sprite will be scaled to fit.

Comment: Please post a screenshot to give us an idea of what the scale should be and what it actually became.

Comment: @PowerUser This looks like code that would compile, but the scale parameter is unused in your method. It doesn't do anything if you send it but don't use it in the code. You would have to pass it to the spritebatch or use it to interact with your other parameters somehow.

Comment: How big is the texture versus how big is the destination rectangle. I'll bet the destination rectangle is a lot bigger than the texture. Thus, "the sprite will be scaled to fit.".

Comment: @Dunk They are multiple sprites actually, the single sprite is 52x88. I'll upload a screenshot in my question in a minute.

Comment: At first glance I read "sprites get terribly scared"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you are using this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433987.aspx, which instead of specifying a scale, specifies destination and source rectangles.

It's hard to tell from the names you chose if you provided the correct rectangles, but you specified `g_BotInvadersRect[r, c]` as the destination (screen bounds) and `g_BotInvaderHitBox` and the source (spritesheet location).

If you place a breakpoint on that draw method and take a look at the value of `g_BotInvadersRect[r, c]`, you should see the actual destination rectangle for that sprite, which according to your problem description is the wrong value. Your issue is most likely that your destination bounds were not calculated correctly.

Comment: You are correct about the rectangles. Even so how can I change `g_BotInvadersRect[r, c]`'s size?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by changing the size of the destination rectangle. How did you define it in the first place?

Comment: It's in the question: `public static Rectangle[,] g_BotInvadersRect;`. I didn't define any size to it? Also if the size is wrong it should be changed to the correct value.

Comment: you are right, the width of the destination rectangle is 156 for every sprite, where it should be exactly 52. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where do you assign the values to ```g_BotInvadersRect```?

Comment: Look at the code under my screenshot in the question body.

Comment: Ooooh. I found the problem! This line of code: `g_BotInvadersRect[r, c].Width = g_BotInvaderTex.Width;`! Since my texture contains many sprites it gets the width of the  entire texture and not the sprite itself, I changed it. Thanks anyway I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: You might be reassigning it elsewhere or don't assign it in the correct place. Also, is ```g_BotInvaderTex``` in a spritesheet or a separate sprite like in your post?

Comment: If it's a spritesheet, you might be getting the wrong width because you're assigning the width of the spritesheet and not of the sprite.

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: Yeah it was just as I thought - something simple I'm forgetting about. :)